# What is the Halo2 zkp scheme's time complexity？

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

The Halo2 is the zero-knowledge proof scheme which is the improvement of [HALO](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1021.pdf). However, it is not clear for me what is the time complexity of this scheme，including generating and verifying the proof. Thank you!